# How to estimate how important each word is for classifying a label in Naive Bayesian?

Tags: r, r-caret, naivebayes

I am training a Naive Bayesian model to predict the movie review type. The model has been created and works well, but I am stuck with the question that how I can estimate how important each word is for classifying a label by ranking the words by their conditional probabilities within the likelihoods.

The task is to train a naive bayesian model to predict the type of a movie review, positive or negative. After training the model, I wrote the "nbclassifier$table" to show a list of each feature's conditional probability. Then I don't know how to select the top 5 most distinguishable feature for positive reviews and other top 5 for negative reviews.

```
rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE)) 

library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(quanteda)
library(readtext)

library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(ElemStatLearn,foreign,class,caret,e1071) 

url = "http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~janastas/data/movie-pang02.csv"
dataframe <- readtext(url, text_field = "text")

## change the column names for own use
colnames(dataframe) <- c("doc_id", "text","posneg_type")

## creating corpus
doc.corpus <- corpus(dataframe)
summary(doc.corpus,5)

#remove punctuation, remove numbers, remove all the spaces, stem the words, 
remove all of the stop words, and convert everything into lowercase.
doc.corpus.dfm <- tokens(doc.corpus,  
                     remove_numbers = TRUE, 
                     remove_symbols = TRUE, 
                     remove_url = TRUE,
                     remove_punct = TRUE,
                     remove_twitter = TRUE,
                     remove_separators = TRUE) %>%
tokens_remove("\\p{P}", valuetype = "regex", padding = TRUE) %>%
tokens_remove(stopwords("english"), padding  = TRUE) %>%
tokens_remove( "s", padding = TRUE)  %>%
tokens_remove( "t", padding = TRUE)  %>%
tokens_ngrams(n=1) %>%
tokens_tolower() %>%
tokens_wordstem() %>%
dfm()

doc.corpus.dfm <- dfm(doc.corpus.dfm)

doc.corpus.dfm.sparse <- dfm_trim(doc.corpus.dfm, sparsity = 0.9)

reviewsDTM_F <- data.matrix(dfm_weight(doc.corpus.dfm.sparse, scheme = 
"count"))

## Train a naive Bayes classifier called "nbclassifier" with a 70\%/30\% 
training/testing split
# convert to a dataframe
reviewsDTM_F <- as.data.frame(reviewsDTM_F, stringsAsFactors =  FALSE)
# set NA values to 0
reviewsDTM_F[is.na(reviewsDTM_F)] <- 0

sum(is.na(reviewsDTM_F))

## Creating training dataset
reviewtrunc <- data.frame(yvar = 
factor(doc.corpus.dfm@docvars$posneg_type), reviewsDTM_F)

# Resample the data
train <- sample(1:dim(reviewtrunc)[1]) #Random Indices shuffling helpful
reviewtrunc.train <- reviewtrunc[train[1:1400],]
reviewtrunc.test <- reviewtrunc[train[1401:2000],]

set.seed(20191013)

## Train the "nbclassifier"
nbclassifier <- naiveBayes(yvar ~ ., data = reviewtrunc.train)

## Now predict the test data
test_pred <- predict(nbclassifier, reviewtrunc.test[ , 
names(reviewtrunc.test) != "yvar"])

## Retrieve the probabilities of each term from nbclassifier
nbclassifier$tables
```

So, how can I use the "tables" data from the "naiveBayes" function which provides these conditional probabilities, provide a list of the top 5 terms which predict positive review and a list of the top 5 terms which predict negative reviews.

Comment: A pretty straightforward way to  rank features by importance is by using [permutation importance](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/feature-importance.html). Another way would be [SHAP feature importance](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/shap.html#shap-feature-importance).

Comment: Hi missuse, thanks a lot. I'm sorry but could you elaborate the command in r a little bit more?

Comment: The simplest way I can think of for  permutation importance is to use [mlr](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/index.html). The function [`generateFeatureImportanceData`](https://rdrr.io/cran/mlr/man/generateFeatureImportanceData.html) performs this. The learner would be [`classif.naiveBayes`](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/integrated_learners.html). The principle is based on a part of the famous paper by Friedman; [Greedy Function Approximation: A Gradient Boosting Machine](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1013203451). Read the first three mlr basics tutorials.

Comment: While this may not provide the same order of features (words) as would ranking them by naive Bayes coefs, I trust that permutation importance is a much more robust metric.

Comment: Hi Missuse, thank you so much! I think I got your idea about the `mlr` after watching the tutorials. I got a feature list and it's a little bit different from the ranking method, but that's totally fine. Thanks again!